# How to Download files from the internet with powershell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, batch-file, download

I want to make my PowerShell download a file from the internet. So how could I do that my original code was `$File = URL`
`Download file.WebClient = File.ext`

Comment: You appear to be trying to post questions that you can answer yourself. This isn't a problem per se, but the questions you're posting are not clearly phrased, show little of the effort or "home work" that we expect askers to present. We recognize that English not being a first or native language may play a roll in this, but it would be better if you spent the time to make your questions good questions, rather than what appears to be creating a collection of very rudimentary and simplistic questions that are already answered elsewhere, or that have sufficient documentation elsewhere already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common thing and very well documented all over the web and in Youtube videos. [A quick web search would have given you the options.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=download%20files%20powershell&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=download%20files%20powershell&sc=8-25&sk=&cvid=E1BD6835E3654F219E3BD085042B3263)
There are multiple ways to do web downloads.

Hit(s) from the search above:

[3 ways to download files with PowerShell](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

> 1. Invoke-WebRequest
>
> The first and most obvious option is the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. It
> is built into PowerShell and can be used in the following method:

```
$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

> 2. System.Net.WebClient
>
> A common .NET class used for downloading files is the
> System.Net.WebClient class.

```
$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
#OR
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

> 3. Start-BitsTransfer
>
> If you haven't heard of BITS before, check this out. BITS is primarily
> designed for asynchronous file downloads, but works perfectly fine
> synchronously too (assuming you have BITS enabled).

```
$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date

Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
#OR
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: That works too though I was Showing a specific way to do it with a few lines of code.